# How can I downsample a dataframe taking the highest value?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with 5min values and I want to downsample it to 30min using the highest value? It is a price dataframe and I need to know the highest prices by time.

I tried

df = df.resample(‘30T’).max()

And it returns me the last value instead of the highest.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please review [ask] and provide a [mcve], including a sample input/output and your current attempt.

Comment: Check this link. I think this has what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44789716/pandas-resample-dataframe-column-get-discrete-feature-that-corresponds-to-max